# Play 2.4.1 injecting Logging filter as in given example

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I try to implement the *LoggingFilter* as in the example given on https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.1/ScalaHttpFilters with Play 2.4.1 .

**FilterConfiguration**
    import javax.inject.Inject
    import play.api.http.HttpFilters

```
class FiltersConfiguaration @Inject()(loggingFilter:com.holidaycheck.filters.RequestLoggingFilter) extends  HttpFilters {
  val filters = Seq(loggingFilter)
}
```

**Filter**

```
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

object RequestLoggingFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {

      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

      nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

       val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
       val requestTime = endTime - startTime

    Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri}" +
      s" took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")
    result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)

    }
  }
}
```

}

**configuration**
I do as given in the explanation, also giving the filters in the `application.conf`.

```
play.http.filters = com.holidaycheck.filters.FiltersConfiguaration
```

But I get the following Error:

[image: Error]

[image: Path in IntelliJ]

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to inject an `object` in your `FiltersConfiguaration`. Make `RequestLoggingFilter` a `class` should solve your problem.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks. Looks like the documentation is wrong here.

Comment: It's a little confusing indeed. If you look close they are using a class in the first example ("A simple logging filter").

Comment: Pull requests are always welcomed ;) https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/working/scalaGuide/advanced/http/code/EssentialFilter.scala#L8